# ESPN Table does not have TR/TD tags

Tags: python, beautifulsoup

[ESPN Website View](https://i.stack.imgur.com/MNtSo.jpg)

I'd like to pull live auction/draft data from ESPN into a python script that adjusts player valuations / probability of being picked. The table on the page though, doesn't have TD/TR tags. It just has a lot of Div / Class. When trying different variations of find/findall for a lot of the Class' that I see in Chrome's inspector, I never seem to return any results.

```
import requests, bs4
url = "https://fantasy.espn.com/football/draft?leagueId=93589772&seasonId=2019&teamId=17&memberId={19AD42D6-8125-489D-B045-1E535CFC02E4}"
r = requests.get(url)
soup = bs4.BeautifulSoup(r.text, 'lxml')

table = soup.find("main", {"class": "jsx-2236042501 draftContainer"})
print (table)
```

these draft links only last so long, so unfortunately it won't be live for much longer.

Answer (score 1):

The contents of the table are loaded with Javascript. You must use browser automation such as Selenium to extract the DOM after Javascript has loaded the page contents.